# How to position two images next to each other

Tags: css, image, css-position

How can I position two images next to each other and then add `<div>` with smaller `width` and make `overflow: hidden`?

Like in slider. I always got stacked images (block level), but I need inline.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
 
.slider div {
    background-color: red;
    position:relative;
}
img {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider"><div>
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Lg1sxGxpUtviON3zqYv_Pjz_gLMf2YhlOvuFPe1-zfusYQum6pOfMrXRCxR6MfnUoJ7IK2VAihsNxJkL0qhmRVRo1vxTpClk_970lE6gp5XQ" alt="">
        <img src="https://imgcomfort.com/Userfiles/Upload/images/illustration-geiranger.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Lyuba, what did you try so far?

Comment: To general Q. Endless ways to put two images next to each other (By inline-block. Flexbox. CSS Grid. Table. Floating). Please read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction. And later add more specific Q. Also please add a screenshot of the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox.

Flexbox is a great way for arranging items in a row or a column. All items inside a flexbox are placed next to each other in the same direction. The default direction is row, but you can use `flex-direction` on the flex container to alter that. Here's a complete guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Oh and of course you need to use `overflow: auto` if you want scroll behavior when the box is smaller than the content.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
 
.slider {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Lg1sxGxpUtviON3zqYv_Pjz_gLMf2YhlOvuFPe1-zfusYQum6pOfMrXRCxR6MfnUoJ7IK2VAihsNxJkL0qhmRVRo1vxTpClk_970lE6gp5XQ" alt="">
  <img src="https://imgcomfort.com/Userfiles/Upload/images/illustration-geiranger.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```